# How can i transform the code below to functional style?

Tags: java

The code below is doing a left join.
the output result is

```
(1,1),(2,null),(3,null),(4,null),(5,5).
```

How can I transform the code to functional style just using streams?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;


public class Hello {

    static <T> Stream<T> defaultIfEmpty(
    Stream<T> stream, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    Iterator<T> iterator = stream.iterator();
    
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            return StreamSupport.stream(
                Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                    iterator, 0
                ), false);
        } else {
            return Stream.of(supplier.get());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> s1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2,3,4,5);
        List<Integer> s2 = Arrays.asList(1, 3,6,2,5);
 
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> output = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // Imperative approach
        int index = 0;
        for(Integer item : s1)
        {            
            Integer item2 = s2.get(index);
            if(item == item2) { output.add(Pair.of(item,item2)); }
            else { output.add(Pair.of(item,null)); }            
            index++;
        }
        
        // Functional style.
        // does not compile.
        s1.stream().flatMap(v1 -> s2.stream()
                   .filter(v2 -> Objects.equals(v1, v2))
                   .onEmpty(null)                                 
                   .map(v2 -> Pair.of(v1, v2)))
                   .forEach(System.out::println);
              
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There is nothing like `Stream#onEmpty`.

Comment: "does not compile" isnt a proper problem description. See [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   IntStream.range(0, s1.size())
            .mapToObj(x -> {
                int left = s1.get(x);
                int right = s2.get(x);
                return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(left, left == right ? right : null);
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is rather trivial, just find out each element and compare; not much different than the imperative approach. And you do not need a `Pair` class, java already has `Map.Entry`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the code given by the OP says `does not compile` so I am wondering if he wants another solution, or an explanation why his code doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Streams! I remember going through many of these excercises. With each one of these, you get a lot better at it. All you need is some better syntactic sugar to get to what the imperative side does.

First, in streams, always consider what output you want.. In your case, it's:
List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> output

To get that, you must stream over both lists. Well done finding flatMap. That's exactly what you want. FlatMap expects you to RETURN a -stream- inside of its method, too. So I wrote this one to do just that. And you'll also need to "collect" the stream into a list, since that's what you had above. To do that, use the Collectors! Lots of collectors can be used.. Map collectors.. Grouping by.. and basic Lists are of course a crowd favorite. Good luck on your adventure!

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> matches = s1.stream()
        .flatMap(v1 -> {
            return s2.stream()
                .filter(v2 -> Objects.equals(v1, v2))
                .map(v2 -> Pair.of(v1, v2));
        })
        // Can "forEach" if you like but it won't return a list.
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I temporarily took out your empty check filter. You probably want to leave that in, but while that may be important data-wise, I wanted to focus on explaining the more important stream concepts.